# How to convert data frame types Object to Integer / float?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Hi I do exercise with data from [Telco Costumer Churn](https://www.kaggle.com/blastchar/telco-customer-churn#WA_Fn-UseC_-Telco-Customer-Churn.csv), I want to convert column "TotalCharges" data types from object to integer but when I run

```
df_1['TotalCharges'].astype(str).astype(int)
```

always end with error ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '29.85'

Comment: The error message is clear, you can't convert `'29.85'` to `int`. What do you expect this casting to give you?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `float()` to convert your string to a float, then `int()` to get the (truncated) integer or `round()` if you wanted the number rounded:

```
int(float(df_1['TotalCharges']))
```

Answer (score 0):

You should first convert to float then convert to int

`df_1['TotalCharges'].astype(float).astype(int)`

if you consider to be ceil or floor can use
`math.ceil() or math.floor`